# Can I make a method call when accessing /prometheus endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I need to do some calculations when prometheus makes a request to /actuator/prometheus to calculate metrics. Is there such a possibility in the spring boot? It is necessary to do this for the purpose of optimization, at the moment this metric is collected by timer every 3 seconds, which we would like to avoid.